# Spray Dead Letter msg

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray

I'm trying to execute the following code

```
trait CustomHttpService extends HttpService {

  import MyJsonProtocol._
  import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  val offerActor = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props[OfferActor], "offer-actor")

  val defaultRoute = {
    path("offer" / JavaUUID) { uuid =>
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete {
            (offerActor ? Get(uuid)).mapTo[Offer]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class OfferActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case Get(id) =>
      val future = OfferService.genericService.getById(id)
      future.onComplete {
        case Success(s) =>
          s match {
            case Some(offer) => sender ! offer
            case None => println("none")
          }
        case Failure(f) => f
      }
    case id: String => println("received string id: " + id)
    case _ => println("receive nothing")
  }
}
```

Initially I was trying to return directly the future, but it was giving me an error, complaining about the promise that I was trying to cast to my Offer object.

Then I just ugly solve my future inside my actor to finally get the Offer and then return it to the sender.

Doing this I'm getting the following:

> [06/09/2015 15:16:43.056]
>   [spray-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
>   [akka://spray-system/deadLetters] Message
>   [com.spray.entity.Offer] from
>   Actor[akka://spray-system/user/spray-actor/offer-actor#-617290326] to
>   Actor[akka://spray-system/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead
>   letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with
>   configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and
>   'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

Indeed, I'm sending a msg with an Offer that I got from the database.

Instead if I simply create an Offer like this, works perfectly.

```
case Get(id) => sender ! Offer(Some(id), "offer", new DateTime())
```

I'm believing the future.onComplete inside the actor is causing something wrong.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sender` is really a function, so you could write `sender()` to show that it is not just accessing an immutable value.  When you call `sender` inside the future.onComplete the value of `sender` isn't valid anymore.

I've run into this problem before and the way I worked around was by saving the value of sender outside of the future:

```
class OfferActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case Get(id) =>
      val future = OfferService.genericService.getById(id)
      val replyTo = sender
      future.onComplete {
        case Success(s) =>
          s match {
            case Some(offer) => replyTo ! offer
            case None => println("none")
          }
        case Failure(f) => f
      }
    case id: String => println("received string id: " + id)
    case _ => println("receive nothing")
  }
}
```

Comment: That's true! this work around is even better than my own answer because I don't need to worry about blocking any resource.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just solved it trying to block my future.

I just created a blocked version of

```
OfferService.genericService.getByIdBlocking(id)
```

Where I blocked it with

```
Await.result
```

then it worked!

So basically I had to let akka embrace my call with a future using the ask pattern but do blocking operations inside the actor.